# Extract from OSM file only nodes with names

Tags: openstreetmap

I want to create a Gazetteer for the city I live in. For this purpose I downloaded the relevant .pbf file and converted it to a .o5m file using osmconvert. Now I want to use osmfilter to reduce the file to nodes that are tagged with a name. I am aware that there is a "noname=yes/no" tag for some nodes but that does not cover all nameless nodes.

How can I extract all nodes from the .o5m file where the name tag is given a value?

Comment: did you try the following?  ...  --keep="name=*"